# How to create new document with schema?

Tags: mongoose, mongoose-schema

I'm trying to create new document with my schema

```
const schema = new mongoose.Schema({
  room: String,
  messages: Array
})
const ConversationModel = mongoose.model('Conversation', schema)
const Conversation = new ConversationModel()

Conversation.findOneAndUpdate({room: data.room})
```

Console output:

```
UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: Conversation.findOneAndUpdate is not a function
```

I can create it without using schema like this

```
db.collection('conversations').findOneAndUpdate(
    {room: data.room},
    {$addToSet: {messages: ''}},
    {returnOriginal: false, upsert: true}
)
```

But using schema causes this problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create the document with your model instance, i.e.

```
const conversationSchema = new mongoose.Schema({ room: String, messages: Array })    
const Conversation = mongoose.model('Conversation', conversationSchema)
const conversation = new Conversation({ room: data.room, messages: [''] })

conversation.save(err => {
    if (err) return handleError(err)
    // saved!
})
```

or with the create method:

```
Conversation.create({ room: data.room, messages: [''] }, (err, conversation) => {
    if (err) return handleError(err)
    // saved!
});
```

or, for inserting large batches of documents

```
Conversation.insertMany([{ room: data.room, messages: [''] }], err => {

});
```

or with findOneAndUpdate on the model

```
Conversation.findOneAndUpdate(
    { 'room': data.room, messages: [''] }, 
    { '$addToSet': { 'messages': ''} },
    { 'new': false, 'upsert': true }
    (err, conversation) => {
        if (err) return handleError(err)
        // saved!
    }
)
```